# Get JSF managed bean from session

Tags: jsf, session, javabeans, managed

I have a session scoped managed bean that need to be set from another session managed bean, to do this I do the following

```
RWIRManagedBean managedBean = new RWIRManagedBean();
managedBean.setRequest(req);
managedBean.setDisplayAppDetailsMode(new Boolean(true));
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap()
.put("RWIRManagedBean", managedBean);
pageId = ((DoBRServiceViewObj)getConfigMap().
get(ConstantsManager.WebConstants.RWIR_SERVICE_ID)).getServicePageID();
// page id is a jsf page, the belwo is the redirect code
EngineURL engineURL = getRedirectURL(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(). 
                      getExternalContext(),pageId,FacesContext.
                      getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale().getLanguage());
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(engineURL.toString());
```

But when I call the JSF page associated with this managed bean, it looks like if a new managed bean was created and the one I created does not exist.
My question is , the JSF life cycle is supposed to get the managed bean from the session when it evaluate the JSF page, but why it creates a new one in my case? Any help

Comment: What's the scope of `RWIRManagedBean`?

Comment: Are you in JSF 1.x or 2.x? Also remember to mark your questions as answered. You have all of them unmarked, which doesn't encourage people at all to answer your new ones.